Langchain Conversationnal Pipeline (with pipe) + Standalone Question & Chat History + Stream
I'm having an issue with using conversational chains in version 0.1.0 where Pipelines are struggling to work with a chat history. Here's my code:
    ANSWER_PROMPT = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template)
    CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT = PromptTemplate.from_template(history_template)

    memory = ConversationSummaryBufferMemory(
        llm=llm_summarize,
        max_token_limit=max_token_limit_history,
        chat_memory=chat_history,
    )
    loaded_memory = RunnablePassthrough.assign(
        chat_history=RunnableLambda(memory.load_memory_variables) | itemgetter("history"),
    )

    standalone_question = {
        "request": {
            "request": lambda x: x["request"],
            "chat_history": lambda x: get_buffer_string(x["chat_history"]),
            }
            | CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT
            | llm
            | StrOutputParser(),
        "chat_history" : lambda x: get_buffer_string(x["chat_history"]),
    }

    chain = loaded_memory | standalone_question | ANSWER_PROMPT | llm

I present here a conversational chain that deals with a request using a conversation history to generate a standalone question (or request) in order to then add it to a final prompt with the conversation history to respond to the request.
When I replace 'chat_memory' with 'chat_history' in the 'memory' function, it works but does not handle the conversational history... and when I put 'chat_memory' as mentioned above, it usually handles the conversational history well but now I get an error with this type of Pipe when I try a chain.stream on it or chain.invoke with the input = {"request": request}.
   2366 for step in steps:
   2367     final_pipeline = step.transform(
   2368         final_pipeline,
   2369         patch_config(
   (...)
   2372         ),
   2373     )
-> 2375 for output in final_pipeline:
...
---> 62     raise ValueError(f"Got unsupported message type: {m}")
     63 message = f"{role}: {m.content}"
     64 if isinstance(m, AIMessage) and "function_call" in m.additional_kwargs:

ValueError: Got unsupported message type: A

Do you have idea?
So, I would like to ask for your opinions and help on this topic. And the possibility of correction on it, I thank you.
Thanks !

Why not using: ConversationalRetrievalChain? https://billchambers.me/posts/chat-with-your-data-langchain
